# How to insert specific data from Excel columns into a SQL table using a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, excel-2013

I have an Excel file that has the following columns:

```
ID | Name | Location | Purpose | SocialNetwork |
```

Of course, it has data on each column.

I want to import this data into a SQL table but it just has three columns:

```
CompanyID | Name | SocialNetwork
```

How can I do that by using a Query and keeping in mind I have `Excel 2013` and `SQL Server 2012`?

I could do just a query with this code:

```
Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=F:\Company_Data.xls;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Could you try `insert into tablename(companyid, name, socialnetwork) select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=F:\Company_Data.xls;HDR=YES', 'SELECT id, name, socialnetwork FROM [sheet1$]')`?